# How to put Imageview Behind other layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am using a imageview for animation so that it will look like movement left to right.
but my image is displaying front of other views so that user is able to click on image.
i am trying to display it **behind** the other view.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/main_bg2"
    >

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/languageChangePopup"
         style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
         android:background="@drawable/startbtn" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/showOutputEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/display_textbx"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:gravity="right|center"
        android:paddingLeft="70dp"
        android:paddingRight="70dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="3.49">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="136dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/clearBtn"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@string/cbtn" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/sevenBtn"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@string/sevenbtn" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/eightBtn"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@string/eightbtn" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/nineBtn"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@string/ninebtn" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/dotBtn"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@string/dotbtn" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fourBtn"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@string/fourbtn" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fiveBtn"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@string/fivebtn" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/sixBtn"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@string/sixbtn" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/zeroBtn"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@string/zerobtn" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/oneBtn"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@string/onebtn" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/twoBtn"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@string/twobtn" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/threeBtn"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@string/threebtn" />
            </TableRow>

              </TableLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:background="@drawable/operation_planet"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/plusBtn"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/addbtn" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/minusBtn"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/minusbtn" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/multiplyBtn"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/multiplybtn" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/divideBtn"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/dividebtn" />

        </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/equalToBtn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tableLayout1"
                    android:background="@drawable/equaltobtn"
                    android:gravity="right" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/rocketImage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/layout"
                    android:background="@drawable/spaceship" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: RelativeLayout draws its children as you order in xml file, so move imageView to top of relativeLayout and it will be on behind other views...

Comment: Can paste your screen shot here ?

Comment: yahya:- you also gave me good comment answer +1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Put the image view above (on top - first child of the parent)
 the layout in the xml file that way the image will be behind the layout

Answer (score 14):

Use a `FrameLayout`. All items you put in there are stacked on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this in your imageview `android:layout_below="@id/id_of_item_to_show_behind"`